# Nilpotent elements in $\Bbb Z_{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Lets say we have $\mathbb{Z}_9$, why are the only nilpotent elements $\{0,3,6\}$? Aren't all elements in $\mathbb{Z}_9$ nilpotent because $a^9 = 0$ eventually for $a\in \mathbb{Z}_9$? I thought nil potency requires some $n$, not exactly $2$.

Comment: Are you saying that $1^9 = 0$?

Comment: Because $1$, $2$, $4$, $5$, $7$ and $8$ are not nilpotent. They are even units!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom aren't we looking at the additive operation?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i guess not, obviously from your answer.

Comment: @Hawk Nilpotent elements are those that vanish after finite *multiplicative* iteration, not additive iteration. This is considering $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ as a ring, not as a group.

Comment: @Hawk others have said it, but just to confirm: in this context, we're meant to consider $\Bbb Z_9$ as a ring, not a group.  Nilpotency is meant with respect to iterated *multiplication*.

Comment: Never mind I figured out. thanks.

Comment: Euler's theorem says that $a^6=1$ for $\gcd(a,9)=1$, not $a^6=0$. When we look at $\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}\subseteq\Bbb Z_9$ as a multiplicative group, then that, in a sense, means that they are "nilpotent" (we would never use that word, but I can understand the mix-up). Is that what's confusing you?

Answer (score 3):

I feel that this question has alaready been answered and is thus posting this answer as community wiki to remove this question from the unanswered tab, as confirmed by the OP [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591258/nilpotent-elements-in-bbb-z-n#comment5349815_2591258).

The answer is that in this case we're not supposed to consider $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$ as a group, but instead a ring in this context, as nilpotency is meant with respect to iterated multiplication.